# Google map preview selected location on map

Tags: google-maps, google-places-autocomplete, jquery-location-picker

I would like to allow my user to pick a location as well as previewing searched location to pick location.

**Problem**
Am not able to integrate the search-box to preview the searched location.

**Code I am using**

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<div id="map"></div>

var map = document.getElementById('map');

var lp = new locationPicker(map, {
    setCurrentPosition: true,
    lat: -13.9867852,
    lng: 33.77027889
}, {
    zoom: 15 // You can set any google map options here, zoom defaults to 15
});

// Listen to button onclick event
confirmBtn.onclick = function () {
    var location = lp.getMarkerPosition();
    var location = location.lat + ',' + location.lng;
    console.log(location);
};

google.maps.event.addListener(lp.map, 'idle', function (event) {
    var location = lp.getMarkerPosition();
    var location = location.lat + ',' + location.lng;
    console.log(location);
});
```

How do i enable the input to search location and display it on the map

Edit, Have managed to enable search on the input but can't move the marker to the selected location

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('search');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country':['mw']});
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        /*
        console.log(place.geometry['location'].lat());
        console.log(place.geometry['location'].lng());
        console.log(place.name);
        console.log(place.formatted_address);
        console.log(place.vicinity);
        console.log(place.url);
        console.log(place.address_components);*/
        if(!place.geometry) {
            return;
        }


        console.log(place);
    });
}
```

Comment: What marker?  I don't see you creating any marker in the posted code.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: If user type address on the field, the address should be seen on the map - thats what am trying to do - please help

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check out this sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2qpn5cw/3/) that have a search box and a map. When a user selects a place suggestion in the autocomplete input, the sample then calls the getPlace() method, and then it opens an info window to display place details.

You can create an infowindow to display some place details:

```
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">

  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="infowindow-content">
    <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
    <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
    <span id="place-address"></span>
  </div>

  <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
  </body>
```

In the initialize() function, declare your `infowindow` and `marker` objects and then set the marker position and infowindow content in the `place_changed` listener which is called whenever the user selects an autocomplete address suggestion.

```
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -13.9867852, lng: 33.77027889},
    zoom: 15
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('search');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
  autocomplete.setFields(
      ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

  autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
    'country': ['mw']
  });    

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

You can also check out this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) from the public documentation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I implemented one by passing map obj to autocomplete but i have to use yours since it wasn't good implementation.

Comment: it's working but there are two errors, 1 the marker is not moving and only available when i type a location, second i cant pick location by clicking the location unless i type the location. - click the map is not giving location

Comment: Have added `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function (event){ });` to listen for clicks how do i get **['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']** and **latlng** @Angelica